# Given that $W_{1}\cup W_{2}$ is a vector subspace, prove that one of the spaces $W_{i}$ is contained in the other.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that the set-theoretic union of $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ is also a subspace. Prove that one of the spaces $W_{i}$ is contained in the other.

**REMARK**

From the geometric point of view, it is intuitive to interpret it when we consider different lines passing through the origin in $\textbf{R}^{2}$ or different planes passing through the origin when we consider $\textbf{R}^{3}$: there is no way to the proposed result holds unless one line (or plane) is contained in the other. However, I am not able to convert such geometrical interpretation into a proof.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hint: prove the contrapositive by looking at the sum of two vectors, one from each subspace but not lying in the other subspace.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But is it possible to provide a more direct proof to this problem based on the given interpretation?

Comment: Suppose the union of two subspaces of the plane is a subspace. Each subspace is either the origin, a line through the origin, or the whole plane. The result is immediate if either subspace is the origin or the whole plane, so let both subspaces be lines through the origin whose union is either the origin, the whole plane, or a line through origin. The first two are absurd, and you can finish it by arguing that if the union of two lines through the origin is a line through the origin, then the lines coincide.... really, the algebraic proof is simpler, and applies more generally .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that neither subspace is contained in the other. Then there exists $a\in W_1\setminus W_2$ and $b\in W_2\setminus W_1$. Since $a$ and $b$ both belong to the set theoretic union $W_1\cup W_2$, if this is also a subspace then necessarily $a+b\in W_1\cup W_2$. By definition of the set theoretic union, it must hold that either $a+b\in W_1$ or $a+b\in W_2$ (or both). But this leads to a contradiction, since then $b=(a+b)-a$ can be expressed as the difference of two elements of $W_1$, and therefore must belong to $W_1$ since it is a vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are points $w_1 \in W_1 \setminus W_2$ and $w_2 \in W_2 \setminus W_1$.

Since $W_1\cup W_2$ is a subspace, we have $w_1+w_2 \in W_1 \cup W_2$.

If $w_1+w_2 \in W_1$ then $w_2 \in W_1$, a contradiction. Similarly for $W_1$.

Hence we cannot simultaneously have $w_1 \in W_1 \setminus W_2$ and $w_2 \in W_2 \setminus W_1$ and so if $W_1 \setminus W_2$ is non empty we must have $W_2 \setminus W_1 = \emptyset$, and similarly with $1,2$ switched.